# Threadpool in Golang with handling of Goroutines in a Waiting State

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I would want to limit the max number of Goroutines created to avoid creation of too many goroutines. And we can achieve the same by using something like below:

```
var g errgroup.Group
g.SetLimit(10)
for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
    i := i
    g.Go(func() error {
        task(i) //long running task with I/O
        return nil
    })
}
g.Wait()
```

I have created a limit of 10 goroutines above. Next goroutine (which is the 11th) would only run when one of the previous 10 goroutines complete its task. But I want the 11th goroutine to also run whenever any goroutine goes in a waiting state.

How can I achieve that here?

Comment: What you are describing is how goroutines are scheduled normally, with the limit being GOMAXPROCS. Only the runtime can determine when other goroutines are waiting, so you need to have as many goroutines as you want already running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impose restriction on the number of threads for your whole program, then setting GOMAXPROCS would be the right thing to do. However, if you want to limit the concurrency for some part of your program then you can spawn a specific number of workers and then communicate with them using channels.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const maxWorkers = 3

func worker(inputChannel <-chan int, outputChannel chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for val := range inputChannel {
        fmt.Printf("Working with %d\n", val)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        outputChannel <- val + 1
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    workerChannel := make(chan int)
    outputChannel := make(chan int)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    //Spawn workers
    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(workerChannel, outputChannel, wg)
    }
    //Assign work
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            workerChannel <- i
        }
        close(workerChannel)
    }()
    //Close the output channel when the work is done
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(outputChannel)
    }()
    //Wait for output
    for res := range outputChannel {
        fmt.Printf("Got result %d\n", res)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve such a behaviour with combination of a buffered channel and a worker pool:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    taskCount := 1000000
    maxWorkers := 10
    taskChannel := make(chan int, taskCount)

    // Add tasks to the taskChannel
    for i := 0; i < taskCount; i++ {
        taskChannel <- i
    }
    close(taskChannel)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(maxWorkers)

    // Create a semaphore channel to limit the number of concurrent workers
    sem := make(chan struct{}, maxWorkers)

    for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for task := range taskChannel {
                sem <- struct{}{} // Acquire semaphore
                err := processTask(task)
                <-sem            // Release semaphore
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Error processing task %d: %v\n", task, err)
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All tasks completed.")
}

func processTask(task int) error {
    // Simulate a long-running task with I/O
    // Replace this with your actual task logic
    return nil
}
```